# How to break a string at each comma?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

Hi guys I have a problem at hand that I can't seem to figure out, I have a **string (C#)** which looks like this:

```
string tags = "cars, motor, wheels, parts, windshield";
```

I need to break this string at every comma and get each word assign to a new string by itself like:

```
string individual_tag = "car";
```

I know I have to do some kind of loop here but I'm not really sure how to approach this, any help will be really appreciate it.

Comment: have you had a look at the instance methods for your string?

Comment: Visual Studio Intellisense is your friend.  If it's not coming up by setting you can also use ctrl-space to force it.

Comment: There was no need to downvote him... he's obviously new to the site, a simple comment about policy would have been appropriate.

Comment: Sorry guys I must be stupid or something but I get nothing when I compile your code. I must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use one of [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) methods

```
Split Method (Char[])
Split Method (Char[], StringSplitOptions)
Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)
```

let's try second option:
I'm giving `,` and space as split chars then on each those character occurrence input string will be split, but there can be empty strings in the results. we can remove them using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` parameter.

```
string[] tagArray = tags.Split(new char[]{',', ' '},
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

OR

```
 string[] tagArray = s.Split(", ".ToCharArray(), 
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

you can access each tag by:

```
foreach (var t in tagArray )
{
    lblTags.Text = lblTags.Text + " " + t; // update lable with tag values 
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(t); // this result can be see on your VS out put window 
}
```

Comment: Still not working, this is the code I have:                    string tags = "cars, motor, wheels, parts, windshield";
        var individualStrings = tags.Split(", ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string inv in individualStrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(inv);
        }

Comment: I can't access any tags on the tagArray

Comment: can you debug and see are you get values for tagArray or not? `Console.WriteLine` will not write to web page like in console application. try  `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` and you can see the results in output window ( view menu => output window)

Comment: I created a Label and assigned to it like this: lblt.Text = t; when I did this I'm able to see the last word in the string "windshield"

Comment: yes you need to do like this, `lable.Text = lable.Text +"," +inv ;`

Comment: every time you replacing label text for each item, that is the reason you get only final value. hope you understand it.

Comment: Yes, I got Damith. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 10):

No loop needed. Just a call to `Split()`:

```
var individualStrings = tags.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: The only answer that parses his example input correctly, with the bonus of including StringSplitOptions.

Comment: +1 I agree and StringSplitOptions were a good addition to the answer as well.

Comment: this is not compiling, there is no overload method of split with string and StringSplitOptions

Answer (score 7):

make use of [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) function will do your task...

```
string[] s = tags.Split(',');
```

or

[String.Split Method (Char[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448)

```
char[] charSeparators = new char[] {',',' '};
string[] words = tags.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: leading space will be still in the results

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] words = tags.Split(',');
```

Comment: leading space will be still in the results

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the C# [split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) function.

```
string[] tags = tags.Split(',');
```

**Edit**:

```
string[] tag = tags.Trim().Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You should definitely use the form supplied by Justin Niessner. There were two key differences that may be helpful depending on the input you receive:

1. You had spaces after your `,`s so it would be best to split on `", "`
2. `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will remove the empty entry that is possible in the case that you have a trailing comma.

Comment: second option will not compile

Answer (score 3):

### Program that splits on spaces [C#]

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "there, is, a, cat";
        string[] words = s.Split(", ".ToCharArray());
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
there
is
a
cat
```

### [Reference](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split)

Comment: @Damith : Thanks for edit. I just took it from the link that I have provided as Reference.