# How to use Substring function in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to break a string at each comma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901880/how-to-break-a-string-at-each-comma)

I want to split this string  in C#.

```
string str= "ahmad,ehsan,mohmmad,sss";
```

The result must be as below:

```
ahmad
ehsan
mohmmad
sss
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to split it in a list of strings then you can use String.Split function.

```
string[] splitted = str.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split a string, use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
string str= "ahmad,ehsan,mohmmad,sss";
var result = str.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use split method.

```
string str= "ahmad,ehsan,mohmmad,sss";
string[] list=str.Split(',');
foreach(string item in list)
Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Split` method:

```
string[] items = str.Split(',');
```

You *could* use the `Substring` method, that would be like this:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
int start = 0, pos;
while ((pos = str.IndexOf(',', start)) != -1) {
  items.Add(str.Substring(start, pos - start));
  start = pos + 1;
}
items.Add(str.Substring(start));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to split the string, or do you want to replace the `,` with ?

The `string` class has both a `Split` method and a `Replace` method.

```
string str= "ahmad,ehsan,mohmmad,sss"; 
var subStrings = str.Split(',');
foreach (var s in subStrings)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

var newString = str.Replace(","," ");
Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

Answer (score -1):

you the following code,

```
str = str.Replace(',',' '); /* ans will be "ahmad ehsan mohmmad sss" */
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx

if you just want to split the words and want to have as a string array, you can use

```
string[] arr = str.Split(','); 
/*
   ahmad
   ehsan
   mohmmad
   sss
 */
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//use this code 

string str= "ahmad,ehsan,mohmmad,sss";
str.Replace(",", " ");
```

Hope will help you.

Comment: In what way does this answer the question?